# How to insert image in conference paper?

Tags: graphics, floats, ieeetran

I'm learning latex now in college, and I've tried everything I found on the internet but it is not working. 
I'm making a conference paper, that has two columns. I want to insert image that will occupy the space of the columns. So far this is what it looks like: http://prntscr.com/4xgnzm

I have this code about the images:

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {images/} }
```

and inside the document is this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{latexPic}
\caption{\bf {\large Overview of the integrity discovery system using secure introspection}}
\end{figure}
```

Can someone tell me how to format the image so the text is around it and the image is inside the two column space?
PS. This is the first time I am posting here, and I apologize if something isn't according to the rules.
EDIT: I cut as much of the text as I could, but now the problem can't be seen(the image appearing below the text).Anyway here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{ \copyright 2009 ACM 978-1-60558-784-4/09/11...\$10.00 \hfill}
\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\section*{\raggedright{\bf{ABSTRACT}}}
Cloud infrastructure commonly relies on virtualization. Customers

\end{abstract}

\section*{\raggedright{\bf{\Large{1. INTRODUCTION}}}}
Cloud computing holds significant promise to improve the deployment
and management of services by allowing the efficient 
\IEEEpubidadjcol
sharing of hardware resources. In a typical cloud scenario, a user
\section*{\raggedright{\bf{\Large{3. OVERVIEW OF OUR ARCHITECTURE}}}}
Ensuring integrity in a running operating system is a daunting
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{latexPic}
\caption{\bf {\large Overview of the integrity discovery system using secure     introspection}}
\end{figure}
challenge, and one that has been explored for a long time in the
research community. In a system running on real hardware, all integrity
checks need to be done from within the system being monitored,
which inevitably raises the question of how to verify the
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `cuted` package might help: it has a `strip` environment,that temporarily interrupts a two-column setting to place objects full width.

Comment: It isn't clear exact;y what you want or where your problem is, but you may want `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{latexPic}` so the image scales to the column, don't use `[h]` unless you want the figure to float to the end (it mainly acts to prevent `t` op `b` ottom or `p (float) position so makes it hard for latex to position the figure. don't put formatting such as `bf` and `\large` in the caption argument (messes up the list of figures), if you want the figure full width use `\begin{figure*}`

Comment: don't use `bf` in latex2e and don't put formatting in section arguments (unrelated to your figure placement)

Comment: Well how can I flush the section to the left if I don't format it?

Comment: I tried this with the width=\columnwidth but it shrank the image in one column. I want the image to have full page width.

Comment: The formatting of section headings is a choice of the document class, you can change it (eg with titlesec package) but normally if you are using a conference proceedings style you should not do that, the whole point of the class is to enforce the house style on all the articles

Comment: OK you want `figure*` then (2nd version in my answer)

Comment: I realize that I shouldn't touch the Section but in my assignment I need to make conference paper and the sections should be aligned left. Anyway, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: most document classes (eg the standard `article` class) have flush left headings, it is just wrong to choose a class that specifically has centred headings and then put formatting in the section arguments if you do, then at least remove the `{}` as `\large` `\bf` etc do not take an argument and if you have `{\large long heading...}` that breaks over a line you will have large text on a small baseline and it will look horrible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, I include teh figure both as a single column figure and as a double column figure spreading across the next page.

I also removed all formatting commands from inside section heads, and removed the "manual" section numbering.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% so it makes black blobs
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\title{something}
\author{you}
\begin{document}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{ \copyright 2009 ACM 978-1-60558-784-4/09/11...\$10.00 \hfill}
\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Cloud infrastructure commonly relies on virtualization. Customers
\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
Cloud computing holds significant promise to improve the deployment
and management of services by allowing the efficient 
\IEEEpubidadjcol
sharing of hardware resources. In a typical cloud scenario, a user
\section{OVERVIEW OF OUR ARCHITECTURE}

Ensuring integrity in a running operating system is a daunting
\begin{figure}[bhp]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{latexPic}
\caption{Overview of the integrity discovery system using secure     introspection}
\end{figure}
challenge, and one that has been explored for a long time in the
research community. In a system running on real hardware, all integrity
checks need to be done from within the system being monitored,
which inevitably raises the question of how to verify the

Ensuring integrity in a running operating system is a daunting
\begin{figure*}[tp]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latexPic}
\caption{Overview of the integrity discovery system using secure     introspection}
\end{figure*}
challenge, and one that has been explored for a long time in the
research community. In a system running on real hardware, all integrity
checks need to be done from within the system being monitored,
which inevitably raises the question of how to verify the

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the second \begin{figure*} and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Note: use `figure*` for a double-column figure and `figure` for single-column.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is following the @Bernard's indication. In addition i added the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf) package for fine tuning the captions moreover of the *command* `\captionof{...}{...}` to put captions outside of *tables* or *figures*. I think you should put something like

```
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{textfont={bf,large}}
```

in the preamble, and insert the figure like

```
\begin{strip}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{latexPic}
\captionof{figure}{Overview of the integrity discovery system using secure introspection}
\end{strip}
```